# Should i push a solution or a project to github?

Tags: .net, git, github, version-control

i am studying dot-net core and i started with visual studio, when creating a new project visual studio creates a solution and a project inside this solution.
adding my code base to GitHub adds the solution along with the project.
following a tutorial i was introduced to work with visual studio code and i only created a project with no solution.

i pushed a complete solution to GitHub from visual studio
and i push a stand alone project from visual studio Code
i am trying to understand the best practice here to organize my work
my question is as follow, "should i push my projects to GitHub as projects or should i push them as a solution, and even if my projects are inside a solution can i push the projects individually?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions are especially useful for large applications where you might have many projects that depend on each other but whether you commit and push the entire solution or just the projects individually depends on the context of your work (and somewhat personal preference).

Personally, if my projects are interdependent and part of a larger application I commit and push the entire solution to a single repo, so that all dependencies and project references are preserved, and anyone cloning the repository can easily build and run the entire application.

On the other hand, if my projects are independent and can be used separately I have separate repositories for each project so that anyone who wants to run a specific project doesn't have to clone and navigate through unrelated code.

Comment: i mainly work with web forms and win forms. we are trying to move toward a better architecture and upgrade to a newer version of dot-net. mainly the plan is to have a front end project and several web APIs, so i am trying to understand a few things to make the transition smoother and facilitate the development process

Comment: If all the projects are independent they can perfectly be in separate repos. It also depends on your current CI/CD pipeline, etc.